# Generate dynamic R-Markdown blocks with data.table objects

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I would like like to automate this code with a loop on Species in R Markdown.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(data.table)
iris.dt <- data.table(iris)
iris.species <- stringr::str_to_title(as.character(unique(iris.dt$Species)))
```


### View by Species {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}
#### Setosa
```{r}
iris.dt[Species == 'setosa']
```
#### Versicolor
```{r}
iris.dt[Species == 'versicolor']
```
#### Virginica
```{r}
iris.dt[Species == 'virginica']
```
````

I can generate the tabs by using `knit_expand` (actually my question is similar to this one [Generate Dynamic R Markdown Blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729415/generate-dynamic-r-markdown-blocks)) but I struggle to display other inputs like data.table. Here is my attempt:

````
### View by Species automated {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}
```{r run-numeric-md, include=FALSE}
out = NULL
for (i in iris.species) {
  out = c(out, knit_expand(text='#### {{i}}'))
}
```

`r paste(knit(text = out), collapse = '\n')`
````

And here is an overview of the notebook.

[image]

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me if I also generate the R blocks:

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(data.table)
iris.dt <- data.table(iris)
iris.species <- as.character(unique(iris.dt$Species))
```

 ### View by Species automated {.tabset .tabset-fade .tabset-pills}
```{r run-numeric-md, include=FALSE}
out <- vector(mode = "character", length = length(iris.species))
for (i in iris.species) {
  out[i] <- knit_expand(text = c("#### {{stringr::str_to_title(i)}}",
                                 "```{r, echo = FALSE}",
                                 "iris.dt[Species == '{{i}}']",
                                 "```"))
}
```

`r paste(knit(text = out), collapse = '\n')`
````

Comment: You can pass all the character strings to `knit_expand()` as a character vector in a single call.