# How to set the number of columns in a running R flexdashboard

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

My question is an expansion of the [Generate Dynamic R Markdown Blocks question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729415/generate-dynamic-r-markdown-blocks) applied to R flexdashboards.

I made a simple flexdashboard with one numeric input: the number of columns to be rendered in the dashboard body. As I modify this numeric input I expect the number of columns to change accordingly.

- For the static case, where the number of columns is set at the beginning, the solution was provided in the referred question.
- For the dynamic case, where the number of columns is set by `shiny::numericInput()`, I tried modifying this solution by wrapping the R code in `reactive({})` statements.

Here is my flexdashboard.Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Dynamic columns"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(shiny)
library(knitr)
library(flexdashboard)
```

Column {.sidebar data-width=130}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
numericInput(
  "ncols", 
  label = "number of columns", 
  value = 3
  ) 
```

```{r column_generator, include=FALSE}
output <- reactive({
  out <- NULL
  for (i in 1:input$ncols) {
    out <- c(out, knit_expand(text = "### column: {{i}}"))
  }
  out
})
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

`r reactive({paste(knit(text = output()), collapse = '\n')})`
````

I believe I'm close to the solution because I get the following output in my flexdashboard body:

> #### column: 1 ### column: 2 ### column: 3

However, this text is not rendered into three columns by `knit()`.