# RMarkdown: a way to compose a report from many mini-RMarkdown documents?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Consider as an input the tibble:

```r
in_data <- tribble(
~ style, ~input1, ~input2, ~text_input
'style_1', 5, NA, 'first result',
'style_2', 4, 6, 'fun',
'style_1', 2, NA, 'other result')
```

I would like to do the following:

- have different patterns, e.g. `style_1` and `style_2` of the kind

style_1.Rmd

```
---
params:
 input1: NA
 text_input: ''
---
`r params$text_input` is of the value `r params$input1`
```

style_2.Rmd

````
---
params:
 input1: NA
 input2: NA
 text_input: ''
---
```{r}
plot(params$input1, params$input2, main=params$text_input)
```
````

- somehow `in_data %>% pmap(parse_and_knit)` the documents, where every row gets knitted with its corresponding style and arguments, and finally composed into a document, which would need an additional header probably.

There is `heddlr` https://github.com/mikemahoney218/heddlr which does something similar. But it seems to rely on replacing a single argument per "pattern" (which is my "style"). I could make that argument a row number and go pull out data with this information; it would be nicer to take the entire row as `params` input in `pmap` style.

Is that possible? I can just `knit` every piece individually, but I need to compose it to a report in the end, preferably without doing my own DOM magic.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/child-document.html

Comment: @JonSpring thanks, I used that to work out a solution, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Jon Spring, the following is very close to what I want.

- The R script passes the data frame as a `params` item for `rmarkdown::render`
- The logic looping through the rows is in the report template (not, as I initially intended, in the R script that triggers report generation).
- The row data is put into an environment and passed in with `envir`. I could also assign the column variables directly into `envir`, so they could be accessed directly without `data$`, but I'm not yet sure if I want that.
- Note: probably `pwalk(..., ~cat(...))` is better than `cat(pmap_chr(...) %>% str_flatten())`.

### In the script `generate_report.R`:

```
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)
in_data <- tribble(
  ~ style, ~input1, ~input2, ~text_input,
  'style1', 5, NA, 'first result',
  'style2', 4, 6, 'fun',
  'style1', 2, NA, 'other result')


rmarkdown::render("rmdreport.Rmd", params = list(data = in_data))
```

### In the report template `report.Rmd`

````
---
title: "report title"
output: html_document
params:
  data: NA
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, results='asis')
```

# Report

This is the intro to the report. What follows is one block per row in `params$data`.

```{r}

in_data <- params$data

cat(
  pmap_chr(in_data, function(...) {
  data <- list(...)
  envir = new.env()
  envir$data <- data
  knitr::knit_child(glue("{data$style}.rmd"), envir = envir, quiet = TRUE)
}) %>% str_flatten())

```
````

### The individual templates/styles:

#### style1.Rmd

```
## Section on the topic `r data$text_input`

`r data$text_input` is of the value `r data$input1`
```

#### style2.Rmd

````
## Section with a plot

```{r}
plot(data$input1, data$input2, main=data$text_input)
res <- data$input1 * data$input2
cat(glue("{data$input1} * {data$input2} = {res}"))
```
````

Comment: Similar solution here: https://somtom.github.io/post/using-dynamically-rendered-r-markdown-childs-for-reports/ related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729415/generate-dynamic-r-markdown-blocks/21730473#comment65652301_21730473

Comment: This is great, yes Rmarkdown reporting with params and child docs allows for such diverse reporting.  Remember these all have to be in the same directory when rendering too