# Looping headers/sections in rmarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown

I am trying to generate a loop with sections/headers that are followed by a figure in rmarkdown. I understand that I can use cat("## xyz") to generate a new header in my chunk but I observe some odd behaviour.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = F)
```

Version 1: (does not work)

```{r, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:5) {
  cat("\n")  
  cat("## This is a heading for ", i, "\n")

    plot(pressure)
    cat("\n")  

}
```

Version 2: (does not work)

```{r, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:5) {
  cat("\n")  
  cat("## This is a heading for ", i, "\n")

    plot(pressure)
    cat("\n")  

    plot(pressure)
    cat("\n")  

}
```

Version 3 (works):
```{r, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:5) {
  cat("\n")  
  cat("## This is a heading for ", i, "\n")

  plot(cars)
  cat("\n")  

  plot(pressure)
  cat("\n")   
}
```
````

I expect the output to be

**Header 1**

Figure 1

**Header 2**

Figure 2

**Header 3**

Figure 3

etc.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/408#issuecomment-247157358 and https://github.com/r-lib/evaluate/issues/14 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/11956520/7162131

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61330051