# Using `ggplotly` and `DT` from a `for` loop in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt, ggplotly, r-glue

Is that possible to use `ggplotly()` or `datatable()` in RMarkdown from inside a `for` loop or function? Example:

````
---
title: "Using `ggplotly` and `DT` from a `for` loop in Rmarkdown"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2); library(DT)
```

## Without `for` loop - works

```{r}
datatable(cars)

g <- ggplot(cars) + geom_histogram(aes_string(x=names(cars)[1] ))
ggplotly(g) 
```

## From inside the `for` loop  - does not work (nothing is printed)

```{r}
for( col in 1:ncol(cars)) {

  datatable(cars)          # <-- does not work 
  print( datatable(cars) ) # <-- does not work either

  g <- ggplot(cars) + geom_histogram(aes_string(x=names(cars)[col] ) )

  ggplotly (g)            # <-- does not work 
  print ( ggplotly (g) )  # <-- does not work either
}
```
````

I wonder if this is because *interactive* outputs cannot be `print`-ed at all - by design.
No such problem existing when printing non-interactive outputs.

PS
This is related to:
[Automating the generation of preformated text in Rmarkdown using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868942/automating-the-generation-of-preformated-text-in-rmarkdown-using-r)
[Looping headers/sections in rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468804/looping-headers-sections-in-rmarkdown)

Comment: Have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234169/plotly-charts-in-a-for-loop

Comment: Thanks for the link - I looked int it. It does offer a solution, but only if  you just want to loop ggplotly (for that you'll need to stop using ggplot2 and use plotly directly). However, I'm trying to have a combination of text,graphs,tables- all generated automatically after printing each  Section header.

Comment: You can still use ggplotly. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61906480/how-to-display-ggplotly-plots-with-dynamically-created-tabs-and-for-loops/61909785#61909785. Also it is possible to combine different htmlwidgets

Comment: Found this related  link ( `ggplotly` from inside `for` loop in `.Rmd` file does not work).   https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/570 - Seems like it is still not resolved :(

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the solution from the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61906480/how-to-display-ggplotly-plots-with-dynamically-created-tabs-and-for-loops/61909785?noredirect=1#comment110702066_61909785) I added in my comment adapted to your case:

````
---
title: "Using `ggplotly` and `DT` from a `for` loop in Rmarkdown"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(plotly); library(DT)
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
# Init Step to make sure that the dependencies are loaded
htmltools::tagList(datatable(cars))
htmltools::tagList(ggplotly(ggplot()))
```

```{r, results='asis'}
for( col in 1:ncol(cars)) {
  
  print(htmltools::tagList(datatable(cars)))
  
  g <- ggplot(cars) + geom_histogram(aes_string(x=names(cars)[col] ) )

  print(htmltools::tagList(ggplotly(g)))

}
```
````

Comment: this is great.  However I don't get why the cars need to be initiated.  I tried it on my pc and  without the init step it just fails.  The reason why I'm asking is because I have a complicated list of tables that use the for loop through and I can't seem to initiate with a for loop!

Comment: scratch above comment: to get list to work just simply initiate with lappy, like this, ```l = list ( c=cars, c2=iris )
htmltools::tagList(
  lapply(l, datatable)
)```

Comment: Hi @Ahdee. We don't need to init cars. The init step makes sure that the javascript dependencies, i.e. plotly.js and DataTables.js, are included in the html document.

Comment: Or if using `%>%` notation...  ```for(col in 1:ncol(cars)) { 
  cars %>% 
    select(all_of(col)) %>%
    DT::datatable(options = list(paging=F)) %>%
    print(htmltools::tagList(.))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a persistent problem with RMarkdown. Here is the work around however, found [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/570):

```
lotlist = list()

for (VAR in factor_vars) {
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = "mpg", y = "wt", color = VAR)) + geom_point()
    plotlist[[VAR]] = ggplotly(p)
}
htmltools::tagList(setNames(plotlist, NULL))
```