# Output by for loop of DT::datatable with Rmarkdown

Tags: r, for-loop, r-markdown, dt

I want to output datatable several times using for loop on Rmarkdown.

#### test.Rmd

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, include=TRUE, echo=FALSE, comment=NA, results='asis'}
library(DT)

n <- 1

     for (i in 1:3) {
       
       dat <- cars[n,]
       DT::datatable(dat)
       
       n <- n + 1
}
```
````

This code does not print the datatable. I want to do something like the following code in a for loop.

#### test.Rmd

````
---
title: "test"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r, include=TRUE, echo=FALSE, comment=NA, results='asis'}
library(DT)

        dat <- cars[1,]
        DT::datatable(dat)
        
        dat <- cars[2,]
        DT::datatable(dat)
        
        dat <- cars[3,]
        DT::datatable(dat)
        
```
````

Do you know why the for loop does not work? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using \`ggplotly\` and \`DT\` from a \`for\` loop in Rmarkdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685631/using-ggplotly-and-dt-from-a-for-loop-in-rmarkdown)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you!