# plotly objects are invisible in R Markdown

Tags: r, for-loop, plotly, r-markdown

I am new in `R-Markdown` and I have problem with rendering `plotly` objects in HTML report. Problem is with `for loop`. When I create graphs inside `for loop` they are not visible in final report. I found solution for single loop: [LINK](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/273#issuecomment-195611009)
What about situation in double loop? I can't convert the solution from a single loop into, for example, 2 nested loops.
To sum up:

1. **Single `FOR LOOP`**

- plot invisible:

  ```
  plots <- list()
  for(i in 1:3) {
     l[[i]] <- plot_ly(x = rnorm(10))
  }
  l
  ```
- plot visible:

  ```
  l <- htmltools::tagList()
  for (i in 1:3) {
    l[[i]] <- plot_ly(x = rnorm(10))
  }
  l
  ```

5. **Double `FOR LOOP`**

- plot invisible:

  ```
  for(j in 1:3){
  # some text, tables depends of j
  # transform dataset based on `j`
    l <- htmltools::tagList()
    for (i in 1:3) {
       l[[i]] <- plot_ly(x = rnorm(10))
    }
    l # <-plot on the end of each j loop, not on the end of whole loop like was in single for loop
  }
  ```
- plot visible:
  ??

Any idea how to solve that problem? I will be very grateful for any help!

**EDIT**: example of code

```
#' ---
#' title: "Sample Document"
#' output:
#'   html_document:
#'   toc: true
#' theme: united
#' ---

#' R Markdown report of graphs generated with a double (nested) for loop

df <- data.frame(
  j = numeric(),
  desc = character()
)

for(j in c(1:3)){
  cat(paste0("# below we present visualizations for iteration no.: ", j, "\n"))
  
  #' Random table
  #+ echo=FALSE, results = 'asis'
  df <- rbind(df, data.frame(j = j, desc = paste0("iteration no.: ", j)))
  print(knitr::kable(df, row.names = F))
  
  l <- htmltools::tagList()
  for(i in (1:3)){
    l[[i]] <- plot_ly(x = j*rnorm(i*10))
    print(l[[i]])
  }
}
```

Comment: The reason why the first piece of code works is because of R's auto-printing feature: top-level values are automatically printed, i.e. having `l` at the top level inside code is as if you had written `print(l)`. And `htmltools::tagList` overrides `print` to display the plot. The second piece of code does not work because `l` is *not* at the top level, hence it isn't auto-printed.

Comment: @KonradRudolph hmm, then how to make the plots print after each iteration of `j`? Because from what I understand they will never be top level, does that mean it can't be done?

Comment: You can always call `print(l)` (or `plot(l)`, which makes more sense!) explicitly. However, stefan's answer shows a potentially better approach. You can extend that approach to also include text and tables, you just have to construct the entire output progressively.

Comment: I can't call `plot(l)` because I get error:
`Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y'`

Comment: Ah, right, you need to call `plot` on the individual *element* of the list. If you do that you don't need `l` at all (since you don't need to store the plot objects after plotting them).

Comment: you mean:
`l <- htmltools::tagList()
l[[1]] <- plot_ly(x = rnorm(10))
plot(l[[1]])`
If yest, i get the same error

Comment: Ah. Apparently 'plotly' does not define an appropriate `plot` function. That's an unfortunate decision on their part, it might even be worth reporting a bug. So you need to use `print` instead of `plot`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph look at main post, I added example of code with problem that I want to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you could achieve this with the same approach by wrapping the outer loop in a second `tagList`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
date: "2023-04-12"
---

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(plotly)
```

# Using `lapply`
```{r message=FALSE}
htmltools::tagList(
  lapply(1:2, function(j) {
    l <- htmltools::tagList()
    for (i in 1:2) {
      l[[i]] <- plot_ly(x = rnorm(10)) |>
        layout(title = paste(j, i, sep = "."))
    }
    l
  })
)
```

# Using a `for` loop

```{r message=FALSE}
ll <- htmltools::tagList()

for (j in 1:2) {
  l <- htmltools::tagList()
  for (i in 1:2) {
    l[[i]] <- plot_ly(x = rnorm(10)) |>
      layout(title = paste(j, i, sep = "."))
  }
  ll[[j]] <- l
}
ll
```
````

[image]

**EDIT** Adapting my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685631/using-ggplotly-and-dt-from-a-for-loop-in-rmarkdown/62599342#62599342) to your case you could achieve your desired result like so. The important step is to make sure that the JS dependencies are included. Afterwards you could print the plots created in the inner loop using `print`.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  html_document:
    toc: true
    theme: united
date: "2023-04-12"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE)
```


```{r echo=FALSE}
library(plotly)
```

```{r include=FALSE}
df <- data.frame(
  j = numeric(),
  desc = character()
)
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
# Init Step to make sure that the dependencies are loaded
htmltools::tagList(plot_ly(x = rnorm(10), type = "histogram"))
```

```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
for (j in 1:2) {
  cat(paste0("# below we present visualizations for iteration no.: ", j, "\n"))

  df <- rbind(df, data.frame(j = j, desc = paste0("iteration no.: ", j)))
  print(knitr::kable(df, row.names = F))

  l <- htmltools::tagList()
  for (i in 1:2) {
    l[[i]] <- plot_ly(x = j * rnorm(i * 10))
  }
  print(l)
}
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. My situation is a bit different because inside loop `j` I have text, tables etc and graphs generated in loop `i`. To sum up, I would like to achieve a situation where I display graphs with each iteration 'j', and not as a summary of all interactions at the end, as in the solution proposed by you.

Comment: Already guessed that. (: Perhaps you could create a minimal example of what you are trying to achieve. Makes it easier to figure out a solution for your use case. (;

Comment: look at main post, I added example of code with problem that I want to solve

Comment: See my edit for an approach to achieve your desired result.