# Running a loop creating plotly objects and displaying them in a flexdashboard

Tags: r, loops, plotly, flexdashboard

I am running a loop within a flexdashboard that produces plotly objects.  However, no charts are printed.  Is there a bug within the code, or is there a compatibility issue between flexdashboard and plotly?

````
---
title: "flexdashboard with Plotly Loop"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---

```{r}
    library(plotly)
    
    # Your vector of variables
    vec <- c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width")
    
    # Start a flexdashboard tabset
    cat("## Rows {.tabset}\n")
    
    # Loop through each variable
    for (yaxis in vec) {
      
      # Display the heading for the tab
      cat(paste0("### ", yaxis, "\n"))
      
      # Start the Plotly chart chunk
      cat("```{r}\n")   
      
      # Create the Plotly chart
      fig <- plot_ly(data = iris, 
                     x = ~Sepal.Length, 
                     y = ~.data[[yaxis]], 
                     type   = 'scatter', 
                     mode   = 'markers')
      
      # Print the chart
      print(fig)
      
      # End the chunk
      cat("```\n") 
    }

``
````

Answer (score 0):

Adapting my answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685631/using-ggplotly-and-dt-from-a-for-loop-in-rmarkdown/62599342#62599342) which deals with the same issue for a standard R-Markdown document you could create your plotly charts in a loop like so:

1. Make sure that the JS dependencies are included, to this end I added a code chunk which creates an empty plotly chart outside of your loop for which I set `include=FALSE`.
2. There is no need to add the code for a code chunk using `cat()`. Actually this will not work as this only adds the code to your markdown when knitting. However, this code chunk will not get processed.
3. Instead, wrap your plot in `htmltools::tagList()` and `print` the result.
4. Finally, add the chunk option  `results='asis'`.

Full reproducible code:

````
---
title: "flexdashboard with Plotly Loop"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---

```{r include=FALSE}
library(plotly)

plot_ly()
```

```{r results='asis'}
# Your vector of variables
vec <- c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length")

# Start a flexdashboard tabset
cat("## Rows {.tabset}\n")

# Loop through each variable
for (yaxis in vec) {
  cat(paste0("### ", yaxis, "\n"))

  fig <- plot_ly(
    data = iris,
    x = ~Sepal.Length,
    y = ~ .data[[yaxis]],
    type = "scatter",
    mode = "markers"
  )

  print(
    htmltools::tagList(fig)
  )
}
```
````

[image]

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks Stefan.  Do you have a reference to learning the use of js in flexdashboards?