# Rmarkdown print plots in loop on own line

Tags: r

I figured out how to plot graphs in loop with the `print` but it is printing 2 plots per line and getting cutoff.  Even when I add `cat("\n")` it still has 2 plots per line.  How to print 1 plot per line?

```
for (clust in intersecting.001.2.unlog) {
  ex <- row.names(map[map$transcript_cluster_id == clust, ])

  Clotrimazole.exon <- Clotrimazole.e[ex,]
  Clotrimazole.gene <- Clotrimazole.g[as.character(clust),]
  Chlorhexidine.exon <- Chlorhexidine.e[ex,]
  Chlorhexidine.gene <- Chlorhexidine.g[as.character(clust),]
  
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956520/r-knitr-markdown-output-plots-within-for-loop
  print(plot.exons(exonx.drug1=Clotrimazole.exon, 
             genex.drug1=as.numeric(Clotrimazole.gene), 
             rx.drug1=Clotrimazole.r,
             exonx.drug2=Chlorhexidine.exon, 
             genex.drug2=as.numeric(Chlorhexidine.gene), 
             rx.drug2=Chlorhexidine.r,
             ti=clust))
}

for (clust in intersecting.001.2.unlog) {
  ex <- row.names(map[map$transcript_cluster_id == clust, ])

  Clotrimazole.exon <- Clotrimazole.e[ex,]
  Clotrimazole.gene <- Clotrimazole.g[as.character(clust),]
  Chlorhexidine.exon <- Chlorhexidine.e[ex,]
  Chlorhexidine.gene <- Chlorhexidine.g[as.character(clust),]
  
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956520/r-knitr-markdown-output-plots-within-for-loop
  print(plot.exons(exonx.drug1=Clotrimazole.exon, 
             genex.drug1=as.numeric(Clotrimazole.gene), 
             rx.drug1=Clotrimazole.r,
             exonx.drug2=Chlorhexidine.exon, 
             genex.drug2=as.numeric(Chlorhexidine.gene), 
             rx.drug2=Chlorhexidine.r,
             ti=clust))
  cat("\n")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be that your `plot.exons` function is set up to do so? Where's the code for that? I'm sure if you try to do a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), you'll either figure it out yourself or get very quick answers.

Comment: It returns a ggplot object.  Ok i will set a reprex up.